# Stored Procedure take either or variables?

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I'm working in sql server 2005 here and I wanted to know if there was a way to make a stored procedure take variable a or variable b for its parameters.

Right now if I declare A and B it requires both A and B.  Possible to make it take A or B instead?  So that if the other one doesn't have a value it uses the other?

ex:

```
@ID VARCHAR(255)
@MAKE VARCHAR(255)  
AS  
BEGIN  
    SET NOCOUNT ON  
    SELECT *  
    FROM CARS   
    WHERE ID = @ID OR MAKE =@MAKE
```

Thanks!

Comment: edited it in.  Hope that clears it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create procedure MyProcedure
(
    @ID VARCHAR(255) = NULL,
    @MAKE VARCHAR(255) = NULL
)  
AS  

    SET NOCOUNT ON  

    SELECT *  
    FROM CARS   
    WHERE 
        (@ID IS NOT NULL AND ID = @ID)
        OR 
        (@MAKE IS NOT NULL AND MAKE =@MAKE)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IF ID IS NULL
    BEGIN
        /*Code goes here*/
    END
ELSE IF MAKE IS NULL
    BEGIN
        /*More code goes here*/
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        /*Even more code goes here*/
    END
```

I'm quite sure you can call a function using NULL.

And, also do this:

```
@ID VARCHAR(255) = NULL
@MAKE VARCHAR(255) = NULL
```

Read this: http://weblogs.asp.net/stanleygu/archive/2010/02/08/solution-5-implementing-optional-parameters-in-t-sql-stored-procedures.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Stored procedures can take optional arguments.

```
create procedure mysp
    @a varchar(255) = NULL,
    @b varchar(255) = NULL
as begin
   select * 
   from cars 
   where (a = @a and @a is not NULL) or 
               (b = @b and @b is not NULL);
end;
```